# View All Eclipse shortcuts

Tags: eclipse

I was trying to learn all the eclipse shortcuts... I couldn't find anything useful.
There are some shortcuts available for easy ones, like Find, Find in Files, Comment, Uncomment etc.
Is there any way to view all the eclipse shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking Ctrl+Shift+L from eclipse, will list all the shortcuts. This is pretty useful, as you don't need to switch to another window... You can do your work without any interruption.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Open **Windows->Preferences->General->Keys**. Now you can use the filter to find your shortcut and change its binding.

**CTRL + SHIFT + L**

---

Shows you a list of your currently defined shortcut keys.

However this will only show you custom short cuts that user have added therefore, Please find useful eclipse short-cuts below

**CTRL + /**

---

In line Comment

**CTRL + SHIFT + /**

---

Block Comment

**CTRL + D**

---

Delete row. Try it! You no longer need to grab the mouse and select the line, or select Home, Shift + End, Delete. Quick and clean.

**ALT + Up/Down Arrow**

---

Move the row (or the entire selection) up or down. Very useful when rearranging code. You can even select more rows and move them all at once. Notice, that it will be always correctly indented.

**ALT + Left/Right Arrow**

---

Move to the last location you edited. Imagine you just created a class "Foo", and now you are working on a class "Boo". Now, if you need to look at the "Foo" class, just press Alt+Left Arrow. Alt+Right Arrow brings you back to "Boo".

**CTRL+SHIFT+O**

---

Organize imports. What happens when you first use a class you have not yet imported? You will see an error. But when you press this magical combination, all your missing classes will be imported, and the unused imports will vanish.

**CTRL+1**

---

Probably the most useful one. It activates the quick fix. Imagine you create a class, which implements some interface. You will get an error, because the inherited methods are not yet implemented. While you are on line where the error occurs, press this combination to activate the quick fix. Now, select the "Add unimplemented methods" option. You can use the quick fix at every error you ever receive.

Quick fix comes in handy in other situations too. My favorite is the "Split variable declaration". Sometimes I need to broaden the scope of a variable. I activate the quick fix, split declaration, and use alt + arrow to put it where it belongs. You can find even more uses: Convert local variable to field, rename in file, inline local variable, etc...

You could use the "Split variable declaration" on the bar variable, and then move it with Alt+Arrows above the try block..

Or you could use the "Add unimplemented methods" fix here.

The best thing you can do if you see an error is to use the quick fix.

**CTRL+SHIFT+T**

---

Open Type. Imagine, that you need to have a look at the "Foo" class. But, where is the "Foo" class? Is it in the "Boo" project and in the "foo.bar" package? Or somewhere else? With this shortcut, you don't need to know. Just press it, type "Foo" and you are in.

**CTRL+E**

---

Shows you a list of all open editors.

**CTRL+F6**

---

Use to move between open editors. This is a slower alternative to Ctrl + E. It comes in handy in a situation when you want to periodically switch between two editors, something that is nearly impossible with Ctrl+E as it sorts entries quite randomly. Or you might just use Alt+Arrows...

**CTRL+F7**

---

Move between views. When in the editor, press Ctrl+F7 to switch to the Package Explorer, or hold Ctrl and press F7 multiple times to switch to other views.

**CTRL+F8**

---

Move between perspectives. The same as the previous.

**CTRL + F11**

---

Runs the application. What gets launched depends on your settings. It will either launch the last launched class (my preferred way) or it will launch the currently selected resource (the default way). If you want to change its behavior read the previous post.

**CTL + N**

---

Open new type wizard. This is not very quick because you have to select the wizard type (whether you want to create new class, jsp, xml or something else) in the next step. A much faster way would be if you could just hit the shortcut and invoke the particular wizard. It is possible, just keep reading...

**CTRL + M**

---

Maximize or umaximize current tab.

**CTRL + I**

---

Corrects indentation.

**CTRL + SHIFT + F**

---

Formats code. You can make beautiful looking code out of a mess with this. It requires a bit of setup, but it is well worth it. You can find its settings under Window->Preferences->Java->Code style->Formatter

**CTRL + J**

---

Incremental search. Similar to the search in firefox, it shows you results as you type. Don't be surprised if when you hit this combination nothing happens - at the first glance. Just start typing and eclipse will move your cursor to the first occurence.

**CTRL+SHIFT+G**

---

Bind this to "Generate getters and setters". This is a "must have".

**ALT+C**

---

Bind this to SVN/CVS "Commit".

**ALT+U**

---

Bind this to SVN/CVS "Update".

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can go `Window - Preferencee - General - Keys` and see all available shortcuts. Also you can reorder keys here.

Also you can read more about eclipse shortcuts [here](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html)